# Apostrophe-CMS change image src

Tags: image, apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

By default, in html images looks like that:

```
<img src="/uploads/attachments/ckghp4r9f002a8bp5d07gjtfh-docTitle.two-thirds.png" />
```

Can I change this to show a user sth like this?

```
<img src="/uploads/attachments/cuteCat.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Apostrophe makes multiple copies of the image of different sizes (the `.two-thirds` part) and then uses a random `_id` (the `ckghp4r9f002a8bp5d07gjtfh` part) to avoid naming conflicts. So in Apostrophe 2.x there isn't a way to make it use the file name instead. It might be something we explore in 3.x.